# How can I link the file name to the file?

Tags: 8, theming, files

I created a content type with a "file" *field type*. This to upload a pdf file.
Now I want to create a link to open that specific file, in my twig.

If I do this :  `<div>{{content.field_menukaart}}</div>`, it opens my file correctly. But I want another link text other than my filename. For example "open here".

This is where I get stuck. How could I do this ?

This is not working :  `<div><a href="{{content.field_menukaart}}">open here</a></div>`

Thank you for your help,
Basiel

Comment: You should write a custom field formatter for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve by implementing a preprocess function

/themes/mytheme/**mytheme.theme**

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_file_link(&$variables) {
  $variables['link']['#title'] = t('Open Here'); // change title
  $variables['link']['#url']->setOption('attributes', ['target' => '_blank']); // open in a new browser tab
}
```

Rename `mytheme` to your actual theme name and clear/flush caches so hook gets picked up.